# How to use the hover event inside a jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-hover

I am making a simple star rating plugin. But I have a problem putting `hover` event in this plugin.

jquery,

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

        rater: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $this = this;

            $this.set_votes = function(object)
            {
                $(".replacement-radio",object).each(function(){

                    // Set variables.
                    var object = $(this);
                    var object_checked = object.attr('checked');

                    // Check if the object is checked.
                    if(object_checked === 'checked')
                    {
                        // Change stars.
                        $(this).next().prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');
                        $(this).next().nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover'); 
                    }


                });

            }

            $('.button-star').hover(  
                // Handles the mouseover. 
                function() {  
                    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');  
                    $(this).nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover');  
                },  
                // Handles the mouseout . 
                function() {  
                    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().removeClass('button-star-hover');  
                    $this.set_votes($(this).parent());
                }  
            ); 

            // You must call return after declaring the functions.
            return this.each(function() {

                // Set the object.
                var object = $(this);
                //alert(object.html());

                // Check if the object is present.
                if(object.length > 0)
                {
                    // Hide the object and add the star after it.
                    object.hide();
                    object.after('<span class="button-star"></span>');

                    // Attached click event to the button which created after the object.
                    $('.button-star').click(function(){


                        // Set the value into the radio button.
                        var $this_check = $(this).prev().attr('checked', true);
                        var $this_value = $(this).prev().val();


                    });    
                }

            });

        }
    });

})(jQuery);​
```

I am not sure how to call/ use the `hover` event in a plugin actually. Therefore the hover event below does not work inside my star rating plugin,

```
$('.button-star').hover(  
    // Handles the mouseover. 
    function() {  
        $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');  
        $(this).nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover');  
    },  
    // Handles the mouseout . 
    function() {  
        $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().removeClass('button-star-hover');  
        $this.set_votes($(this).parent());
    }  
);
```

Here is the jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/RgBqh/3/).

Any idea how should I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".replacement-radio").rater().binds();
});

(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        rater: function(options) {
            var $this = this,
                defaults = {}, 
                options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            $this.set_votes = function(object) {
                $(".replacement-radio", object).each(function(i,elm) {
                    if ($(elm).prop('checked')) {
                        $(elm).next().prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');
                        $(elm).next().nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover');
                    }
                });
            }

            return this.each(function(i,elem) {
                if ($(elem).length) {
                    $(elem).hide().after('<span class="button-star"></span>');
                    $('.button-star').on('click', function() {
                        var $this_check = $(this).prev().prop('checked', true),
                            $this_value = $(this).prev().val();
                    });
                }
            });
        },
        binds: function() {
            $('.button-star').on({
                mouseenter: function() {
                    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');
                    $(this).nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover');
                },
                mouseleave: function() {
                    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().removeClass('button-star-hover');
                    $this.set_votes($(this).parent());
                }
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RgBqh/14/)

You seem to be using a lot of uneccessary variables, the same names on variables, and even though they are in different scopes, it's confusing within the same main function.
Also `prop()` would be the correct method for `checked`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wait until all the rater code is executed and the class "button-star" is dynamic added, if you run the handler code inside that function the classes are not yet there so there is nothing to hook the handlers to.

***Off topic***:
If your application start to get bigger could take a look at Backbone.js or Knockout.js, they can help a lot to make your code more Object oriented and easy to maintain.

here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".replacement-radio").rater();
    $(".replacement-radio").AttachHandlers();
});



(function($){

    $.fn.extend({ 

        rater: function(options) {

            var defaults = {
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            var o = options;

            var $this = this;

            $this.set_votes = function(object)
            {
                $(".replacement-radio",object).each(function(){

                    // Set variables.
                    var object = $(this);
                    var object_checked = object.attr('checked');

                    // Check if the object is checked.
                    if(object_checked === 'checked')
                    {
                        // Change stars.
                        $(this).next().prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');
                        $(this).next().nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover'); 
                    }


                });

            }        

            // You must call return after declaring the functions.
            return this.each(function() {

                // Set the object.
                var object = $(this);
                //alert(object.html());

                // Check if the object is present.
                if(object.length > 0)
                {
                    // Hide the object and add the star after it.
                    object.hide();
                    object.after('<span class="button-star"></span>');

                    // Attached click event to the button which created after the object.
                    $('.button-star').click(function(){


                        // Set the value into the radio button.
                        var $this_check = $(this).prev().attr('checked', true);
                        var $this_value = $(this).prev().val();


                    });    
                }

            });

        },
        AttachHandlers: function(){
            $('.button-star').hover(  
            // Handles the mouseover. 
            function() {  
                    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');  
                    $(this).nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover');  
                },  
                // Handles the mouseout . 
                function() {    
                    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().removeClass('button-star-hover');  
                    $this.set_votes($(this).parent());
                }   
            ); 
        }
    });

})(jQuery);​
```

doing it as a separate function like this works.

http://jsfiddle.net/RgBqh/9/

Answer (score 1):

You're attaching hover events to elements that don't exist - you create the `button-star` spans in the return statement at the bottom.

If you change your events handler to use event delegation via `on()`, it works fine:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.button-star', function() {
    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().addClass('button-star-hover');  
    $(this).nextAll('.button-star').removeClass('button-star-hover');  
})
.on('mouseleave', '.button-star', function() {
    $(this).prevAll('.button-star').andSelf().removeClass('button-star-hover');  
    $this.set_votes($(this).parent());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/RgBqh/11/

Comment: @lauthiamkok you may want to consider performing all of your logic in the `rater` function, instead of some in the function and some in the return statement - it leads to confusion and problems such as this one.

Comment: thanks for the thought. any better ideas how I can improve it to avoid confusions?

Comment: @lauthiamkok there are many ways you could improve the code, but that question would be better suited for the [code review stack](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: hover() is a shorthanded version of xxx.on( mouseenter ... ).on( mouseleave ...)  there is no need to change that.

Comment: @Cfontes if you do not pass a selector parameter to `on()`, it will not use event delegation. hence the `hover()` shorthand function is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @jbabey I don't understand it. what's the difference when I do this `$('.button-star').hover(fun(),fun())` and your approach ?

Comment: @Cfontes check this fiddle, it may clear things up for you. http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/BbTQ6/